# Events automatically call event in superclass

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events

If an event is called in a derived type, then is the base type event automatically called? For example, if you handle the .LOAD event in the code behind then is Page.Load automatically called (from the Page class)? I would usually test this using Reflector (by stepping through the code), but the trial period has just expired (I am going to buy it tomorrow).

Comment: How about writing a tiny, simple application and try it out right by yourself? Simply set breakpoints (derive _two_ times from `Page` to see).

Comment: I have done this and it does appear to be the case.  I cannot find any documentation from Microsoft.

Comment: @w0051977 It is not immediately documented as it is just basic inheritance.. Also read [this article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ConstructorInheritance.aspx)

Comment: @Styxxy, I am talking about the base type event, not the constructor.  I have edited the question.

Comment: @w0051977 : sorry, my bad, read the question wrongly then. My apologies.